# Minecraft worlds regularly getting lost!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing Minecraft on Ubuntu, running it with the following command (in a bash file)

```
padsp java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar /home/lagerdalek/Games/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar
```

Over the last 4 weeks I have lost 5 worlds.

This is not the problem where a world is no longer visible from the menu, and I need to rename level.dat; rather, it is visible as a save game, but when I open it, it is a new, freshly generated world! Once it was the chunk I had saved with all other chunks deleted, but otherwise it is new.

Minecraft had not crashed, rather I had saved the game and exited by closing the window.

This is getting very annoying. If anyone else is suffering from this problem, have you found a work around? Should I back up saves after I finish a game or is it too late by then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much testing I narrowed this down to a firewall problem.

When I run ufw (the vanilla Linux firewall), it was a regular occurence, now, not any more.

It's not so good running without a firewall, but my start up minecraft bash script stops it for me, and I just have to remember to turn it back on again afterwards :(

Why the firewall deleted worlds for me, I don't know. I suspect it is related to the randomly moving spawn point bug, which Notch claims is fixed, but I don't want to risk losing my 5 month old world just to test it.

Comment: you could try using something like [inotify](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5515/863) to write a script that regularly backs up your savegame while you play minecraft with the firewall turned on, maybe you can then even localize the event responsible for the deletion

Answer (score 2):

One work around is to run your own Minecraft server. The a dis-advantage this the Nether isn't currently working. You can launch the Minecraft server to load single player worlds. Just find your old ./world# folder in your .minecraft directory. When launching the server be sure your world matches the world name in the server.properties file.

I believe Mojang mentioned going this route in the future with Single player. Having the client launch a server instance locally and connect to it.

When this is fixed in future versions it should be a simple copy of the ./world folder back to your .minecraft directory and you will be able to load the world normally again.